# Dividing two equations to find a ratio

Tags: physics, ratio

The question is:

> In the moon, the acceleration due to gravity is $1.6 m/s^2$. Calculate the difference in the period (the ratio) of two identical pendulums if one were on Earth and one on the Moon.

Can someone shine a light on how to answer this question? I believe I have to divide the two equations to get the ratio, but I'm unsure of how to do that successfully.

$T_1 = 2π√(L/g) / T2=2π√(L/1.6)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g_0$ the earth gravity acceleration and $g_m$ the moon gravity acceleration. 
$$\frac{T_0}{T_m}=\sqrt{\frac{g_m}{g_0}}=0,403...$$ $T_m$ is 2.476 times larger than $T_0$.